# C (raspberry) Read lines with various lengths from a text file

Tags: mysql, sql, c

I am trying to fetch data from a text file and send it to an SQL database and keep failing. Sometimes the data reaches the database but i always get a segmentation fault. So i'm focussing first on getting data the right way out of a text file.

How do I put 2 lines of text and 1 date into 3 seperate strings for my SQL line?

My SQL output would be this (also since this part seems to work.. sometimes):

```
sprintf(SQLstring,"INSERT INTO TempHumid VALUES(unix_timestamp(now()),%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,'%s','%s',%s)",(temp / 10.0),(rh / 10.0),(light / 500.0),(ph * 10.0),(ligh\
tchk * 1.0),(tab1var1 * 10.0),(tab1var2 * 10.0),(tab1var3 * 10.0),(tab1var4 * 10.0),(tab1var5 * 10.0),(tab1var6 * 10.0),(tab1var7 * 10.0),(tab1var8 * 10.0),(tab1var9 * 10.0),(tab1var10 * 10.0),(text1),(text2),(date));
```

Comment: What is SQLstring? how is it defined? Please add a complete (or at least compilable) program to your question.

Comment: how do you make sure SQLstring points to buffer large enough to keep result?

Comment: don't ever use basic string operations for SQL statements. This is what *prepared statements* are for. Mainly for security reasons, but you get better performance, too. This applies to *any* programming language, for [tag:c] and [tag:mysql], [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html)

Answer (score 0):

In C you can read a text-file line by line this simple way:

(The 'frow' should be large enough.)

```
  char *sql;
  char frow[1024];
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen( txt_file, "r" );

  while ( fgets( frow, sizeof( frow ), fp ) != NULL ) {
    puts( frow );
  }

  fclose( fp );
```

Then you can explode the 'frow' string with the 'strtok' function the way you need it.

And here is an example, how you can INSERT needed datas to your MySQL database:

```
  if ( asprintf( &sql, "INSERT INTO some_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", a, b, c ) < 0 ) {
        syslog( LOG_ERR, "asprintf error!" );
        return (-1);
  }

  if ( sql_cmd( sql ) < 1 ) {       // my function..
        syslog( LOG_ERR, "MySQL error! %s", mysql_error( conn ) );
  }

  free( sql );
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I tried this:

char * pch;
   printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",frow);
   pch = strtok (frow,"%s,%s");
   while (pch != NULL)
     {
       printf ("%s\n,%s\n",pch);
       pch = strtok (NULL, "%s,%s");
     }

But the output i get from the fgets() is:
1 
(newline)
2 
(newline)
3
(newline)
aaa
(newline)
bbb
(newline)
4

While the txt file is: 
1
2
3
aaa
bbb
4

I can only fetch the last char "4" in my sql string, do i have to make strings in the loop of your first sample code?

Comment: In short, how do i get the seperate lines from the file (line1, line2, line3) into the SQL string?

Comment: My SQL thingy:
sprintf(SQLstring,"INSERT INTO TempHumid VALUES(unix_timestamp(now()),%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%5.1f,%s,%s,%s)",(temp / 10.0),(rh / 10.0),(light / 500.0),(ph * 10.0),(lightchk\
 * 1.0),(tab1var1 * 10.0),(tab1var2 * 10.0),(tab1var3 * 10.0),(tab1var4 * 10.0),(tab1var5 * 10.0),(tab1var6 * 10.0),(tab1var7 * 10.0),(tab1var8 * 10.0),(tab1var9 * 10.0),(tab1var10 * 10.0),(line1),(line2),(line3));